# Reading a Txt File in Structure - How to read the Occur Clause of Cobol in Struct in C#.net

Tags: c#, cobol

I am reading a text file which a cobol program reads successfuly. I am writing the replacement code in c#.net using Struct. Here is reference that i am using. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7357/How-to-copy-a-String-into-a-struct-using-C

**Here is the cobol**

```
  05  NUM           PIC X(6)
  05  FLAG          PIC XX
  05  IP            PIC X(12)
```

**Here is C#.net**

```
    public struct ORDER
    {

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 6)] public string NUM;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 2)] public string FLAG;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 12)] public string CUSIP;

    }
```

I am able to read the variables correctly so far to an x position starting from the begining of the 1st line of the text file.

My output is also matching; but this block of Cobol program is having OCCUR clause and I am trying to figure out; how i can add this to the ORDER struct which i have shared above.

```
  05  AN-AREA.
      10  COST        OCCURS 5 TIMES.
          15 TYPE     PIC XX.
          15 ISO      PIC XXX.
          15 CODE     PIC X(6).
          15 IND-X
                      PIC XX.
          15 IND
                      REDEFINES 
                      IND-X
                      PIC 99.
          15 AMT      PIC X(20).
```

Comment: Just so it's clear which side of the language translation you need help with, are you asking as a COBOL developer, a C# developer, both, or neither?

Comment: OCCURS 5 means an array (TABLE in COBOL parlance) of 5 elements. IND REDEFINES IND-X is synonymous with ID-X UNION IND (or whatever the C# syntax is). Does that help?

Comment: I am converting to C#.net; and as i mentioned i am using string builder. Also i am researching to see if using Strcut is better idea. If some one has suggestions on reading Occur as a sub struct inside the main struct in C#.net. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned OCCURS is an array.
So

```
        05 my-array occurs 3
           10 field-1         pic x.
           10 field-2         pic xx.
```

is stored as

```
      byte position       Field

           1              Field-1 (1)
           2              Field-2 (1)
           4              Field-1 (2)
           5              Field-2 (2)
           7              Field-1 (3)
           8              Field-2 (3)
```

You could look at [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/). It can import Cobol Copybooks and display the file
using the imported Cobol copybook. In Record View you will get something like:

[image]

Comment: The cobol program reads a txt file. I am writing the c#.net code to replace the cobol program and hence i am trying to replace the logic how cobol program reads the same file.          
      I understand that it is stored as an array and i am looking to find out how i can add further code to the Struct in C#.net. Also shouldnt it be field-1 (length  = 1 ), field-2 (length = 2) vs how you have listed......?

Comment: I listed byte position (starting a 1 rather than 0), so  field-1 starts at byte 1, field-2 1 byte- byte later at 2; field-1(2) starts 2 bytes later (length of field-2) at 4 etc.

Answer (score 0):

*I am reading a text file*, which I must assume has records separated by CR+LF (or LF). I created a test data file with three records, and used `StreamReader` to process the file.

**Important:** It is possible that the program that created the file you will use truncated trailing spaces. In that case, it will be necessary to append spaces to the record to reach 185 characters before breaking it apart.

I used a `Class` rather than `struct` because there appears to be nothing that requires `unmanaged` types. I used `Substring` to breakup the record.

Since the primary concern is how to implement the `OCCURS` clause, I show how I did that using a nested `Class` array.

My goal, simply, is to show how it *may* be done. Using this as a starting point, others may suggest changes as to how it *should* be done. Take *their* advice.

---

Program:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open(@"z:\data.txt", FileMode.Open)))
            {
                string s;
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (s.Length != 185)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Wrong length record");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Order c = new Order();
                        c.NUM = s.Substring(0, 6);
                        c.FLAG = s.Substring(6, 2);
                        c.IP = s.Substring(8, 12);
                        for (int i = 0, idx = 20; i < 5; i++, idx += 33)
                        {
                            c.AN_AREA[i] = new Order.COST();
                            c.AN_AREA[i].TYPE = s.Substring(idx, 2);
                            c.AN_AREA[i].ISO = s.Substring(idx + 2, 3);
                            c.AN_AREA[i].CODE = s.Substring(idx + 5, 6);
                            c.AN_AREA[i].IND_X = s.Substring(idx + 11, 2);
                            c.AN_AREA[i].AMT = s.Substring(idx + 13, 20);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(c.NUM);
                        Console.WriteLine(c.FLAG);
                        Console.WriteLine(c.IP);
                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(c.AN_AREA[i].TYPE);
                            Console.WriteLine(c.AN_AREA[i].ISO);
                            Console.WriteLine(c.AN_AREA[i].CODE);
                            Console.WriteLine(c.AN_AREA[i].IND_X);
                            Console.WriteLine(c.AN_AREA[i].AMT);
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public string NUM;       //05  NUM PIC X(6)
        public string FLAG;      //05  FLAG PIC XX
        public string IP;        //05  IP PIC X(12)
                                 //05  AN-AREA.
        public COST[] AN_AREA = new COST[5]; //10  COST OCCURS 5 TIMES.
        public class COST
        {
            public string TYPE;  //15 TYPE PIC XX.
            public string ISO;   //15 ISO PIC XXX.
            public string CODE;  //15 CODE PIC X(6).
            public string IND_X; //15 IND-X
                                 //    PIC XX.
                                 //15 IND
                                 //      REDEFINES
                                 //      IND-X
                                 //      PIC 99.
            public string AMT;   //15 AMT PIC X(20).
        }
    }
}
```

Data used:

```
AAAAAABBCCCCCCCCCCCCDDEEEFFFFFFGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHIIJJJKKKKKKLLMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNNOOOPPPPPPQQRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRSSTTTUUUUUUVVWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWXXYYYZZZZZZaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
aaaaaabbccccccccccccddeeeffffffgghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhiijjjkkkkkkllmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmnnoooppppppqqrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrsstttuuuuuuvvwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwxxyyyzzzzzzAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
123
```

Output:

```
AAAAAA
BB
CCCCCCCCCCCC
DD
EEE
FFFFFF
GG
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
II
JJJ
KKKKKK
LL
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
NN
OOO
PPPPPP
QQ
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
SS
TTT
UUUUUU
VV
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
XX
YYY
ZZZZZZ
aa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
--------------------
aaaaaa
bb
cccccccccccc
dd
eee
ffffff
gg
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
ii
jjj
kkkkkk
ll
mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
nn
ooo
pppppp
qq
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
ss
ttt
uuuuuu
vv
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
xx
yyy
zzzzzz
AA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
--------------------
Wrong length record
--------------------
```